# I don't understand why my nested for loop works

Tags: java, processing

The objective is to draw a number of squares on a canvas depending on the defined number of rows and columns:

```
int squareSize = 20;
int distance = squareSize + 10;
int numberofRows = 8;
int numberofColumns = 10;

for (int rows = 0; rows < numberofRows; rows++)
{

    for(int columns = 0; columns < numberofColumns ; columns++)
     {
        square(30 + (distance * rows), 30 + (distance * columns), squareSize);

     }
}
```

I'm confused as of to how the program still executes the code in the inner for() loop when the number of rows is lower than the number of columns. I thought I'd have a problem since it was to my understanding that the inner loop would only be read and executed only and only if the outer loop proved to be true (so in this case, the program would stop working when the number of *rows* reached 8.)

...Yet the program still gives the expected results when I insert a lower number of rows than of columns. Why is that?
EDIT: English isn't my first language so I made a very stupid mistake in my question. Obviously my question is how the code is executed when the number of rows is *lower* than the number of columns. I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Why wouldn't it?  The outer loop iterates from `0` to `numberofRows`, and in each iteration the inner loop iterates from `0` to `numberofColumns`.  What's the problem?

Comment: I suppose you're mixing up maximal value (constant stored in `numberOfRows` variable) and `rows` variable which is changed from 0 to 10

Comment: @David I'm really stupid. I meant the other way around. Why my loop works when the numberofRows is *lower* than the numberofColumns. I'll edit my post ASAP. Facepalm.

Comment: The two variables are different though. `rows` and `columns` are two unrelated integer variables, so their conditions won't interfere with each other

Comment: @AliceR.: Same question though... Why wouldn't it?  Why does the relative value of `numberofRows` and `numberofColumns` matter?  You could create a table with 2 rows and 10 columns, or 900 rows and 6 columns, or 5 rows and 5 columns, etc.  What difference does it make?

Comment: Maybe a spreadsheet metaphor can be used here. So in that case, does it help to think in terms of _cells_ instead of _columns_? Each row is processed one at a time (the outer loop). Each row contains a fixed number of _cells_. Yes, it is true that each cell is part of a _column_ of cells. But really, every time you enter the inner loop, you are processing a set of cells in the current row - and not really a set of columns. Using a debugger to step through the code line-by-line may also help you to visualize the overall flow.

Comment: @David huh... The way I was visualizing for-loops I thought the following: in each iteration the number of rows will go up by one, and the loop will stop once the number of rows reaches numberofRows. In other words the outer loop would only run 8 times, and since we reached the limit of the *rows < numberofRows* condition, then the program won't read and execute what's inside of that loop (the inner loop).

Comment: @AliceR.: *"In other words the outer loop would only run 8 times"* - Correct.  And based on the terminology used in the code I would expect it to output 8 rows of squares.  Is that not what's happening?

Comment: @David I finally understand. My mistake was thinking that the inner loop would only iterate *once*. But what's happening is that once the condition of the outer loop is confirmed, then the inner loop iterates *until* the inner condition isn't true anymore. Only then is the outer loop iterated a second time, and the inner loop is then set back to 0, and so on!

Comment: @andrewJames the spreadsheet analogy was really helpful, and using the debugger made it all "click" for me. Thanks to your and everyone else's explanations I was finally able to understand that I was thinking about nested loops all wrong. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read slowly your code. As said, the two loops are detached one from each other. Also replacing the variables with their values might be useful to understand:

```
for (int i= 0; i< 8; i++)
{

    for(int j = 0; j< 10; j++)
     {
        square(30 + (30* i), 30 + (30* j), 20);

     }
```

}

As you can see the square function first is called with i=0 j=0 then it's:

```
square(30,30,20).
Then i=0, j=1
square(30,60,20)
Then i=0 j=2
square(30,90,20).
...
i=0 j=10
square(30,330,20)
Then the inner for reached the maximum and then you come again to your outer loop and add one to i. 
i=1 j=0 
square(60,30,20)
i=1 j=1
square(60,60,20)
...
i=1 j=10
square(60,330,20)
...
```

keep doing this exercise until the maximum value of i=8 and j=10.

```
square(240,330,20)
```

All these square functions will be called in that specific order with those arguments. If you want further insight please tell what this square function does.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop will execute for `numberofColumns` time's for every execute of the main loop.
So the main loop will execute `numberofRows` time's and therefore the inner loop will execute `numberofColumns`*`numberofRows` time's

Answer (score 0):

Bandolero's answer is great (+1) !

Here is a commented version of your sketch that visualises each iteration step as an animation frame:

```java
int squareSize = 20;
int distance = squareSize + 10;
int numberOfRows = 8;
int numberOfColumns = 10;

int rows;
int columns;
// do we still need to iterate through rows or columns or are we done ?
boolean isUpdating = true;

void setup(){
  size(290, 350);
  frameRate(3);
  reset();
}

void reset(){
  background(255);
  rows = 0;
  columns = 0;
  isUpdating = true;
}

void draw(){
  
  if(isUpdating){
    // render each square
    fill(255);
    float x = 30 + (distance * rows);
    float y = 30 + (distance * columns);
    square(x, y, squareSize);
    // render rows, columns values
    fill(0);
    text(rows + "," + columns, x, y + squareSize * 0.75);
    
    // increment each row
    rows++;
    // if the end of a row is reached, reset the row count and increment the column count
    if(rows >= numberOfRows){
      rows = 0;
      columns++;
    }
    // if we completed columns we're done
    if(columns >= numberOfColumns){
      isUpdating = false;
    }
    
    println("rows=", rows, "/", numberOfRows, "columns=", columns, "/", numberOfColumns);
  }
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(key == ' '){
    reset(); 
  }
  if(key == 'r'){
    numberOfRows--;
  }
  if(key == 'R'){
    numberOfRows++;
  }
  if(key == 'c'){
    numberOfColumns--;
  }
  if(key == 'C'){
    numberOfColumns++;
  }
}
```

Essentially, instead of using the `for` in one frame, it's using each new frame to increment.

Feel free to change the `frameRate()` to something faster or slower and use the `SPACE` key to reset the animation (and `c/C` to decrease/increase `columns` and `r/R` to decrease/increase rows)